# How to represent items in 1s & 0s for generating an initial population in a genetic algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I want to find frequent itemsets from items using genetic algorithms.

My sample transaction database is
`dataset = [['a','b'],['c'],['d'],['b'],['e','c','b'],['a','c']]`
My items are [a,b,c,d,e]

Firstly, I want to represent each item in 1s and 0s. For e.g. `'a' as {1,0,0,0,0} and d as {0,0,0,1,0}`.

How can I do this in Python??

When I have to crossover the items the 1s and 0s will have to transform so this form will have to be mutable.

Can someone please help me or point me to a GA implementation which is kind of like this situation? A pointer would be of great help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
zeros = [0 for item in items]
for index, item in enumerate(items):
  result = zeros.copy()
  result[index] = 1
  print(result)
```

Input:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```